# Autocomplete in Google Apps Script with data from Google Sheets

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script

I am trying to use Google Apps Script to create a form, where the fields allow for autocompletion.  In other forms I’ve created, I’ve been able to pull an array of options from a google sheet, and use them to populate a drop down list, so I have to think it’s possible to do the same with an autocomplete process.

I’ve blatantly copied [this example](https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_js_autocomplete.asp) from w3schools, and it works exactly as needed, as long as I declare the array within the javascript (as done in the example).  But what I haven’t been able to figure out is how to populate the array with options pulled from my google sheet.

Here is where I started:

```
var PMOSupport;

$(function() {
   google.script.run.withSuccessHandler(buildDropDowns)
   .getPMOSupport();
});


function buildDropDowns(data) {
  PMOSupport = data;
  console.log(PMOSupport);
}


function autocomplete(inp, arr) {
  console.log("ENTER AUTO");
  var currentFocus;
  inp.addEventListener("input", function(e) {
  // all of the remaining code is direct from the w3schools example
  // I'm cutting it from here for brevity, 
  // and because I know this works, when using the declared array below
  });
}

var countries = ["Afghanistan","Albania","Algeria","Andorra"];

// this line works fine, when using the array declared above    
// autocomplete(document.getElementById("myInput"), countries);  

// this line does not work, when trying to use the array populated from the google sheet
autocomplete(document.getElementById("myInput"), PMOSupport);
```

When I run this, the page creates, and as soon as I type into the entry field, I get a message in the console:

```
`Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'length' of undefined`
    at HTMLInputElement.<anonymous> (<anonymous>:32:28)
```

When I look into this, it’s saying that the ‘arr’ argument (PMOSupport) isn’t populated.  That’s why I added the 2 console.log lines, to see what order things are happening.  When I open the page, “ENTER AUTO” logs first, then the State Changes from Idle to Busy and Busy to Idle (while it calls getPMOSupport()), then the PMOSupport array logs in the console (also proving that I am in fact getting the correct data back from the sheet).  So clearly, it’s entering function autocomplete() before it calls the google.script.run.withSuccessHandler(buildDropDowns).getPMOSupport() portion, which is why the 'arr' argument is undefined.

I’ve tried various ways of taking that out of the `$(function() … });` block, to try to get the PMOSupport array populated before the autocomplete() function runs.  Nothing I’ve done seems to be working.

I’m sure this is something simple, and caused by bad habits I’ve picked up over time (I’m not a developer, I just cobble things together for my team).  But any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to call `autocomplete` AFTER the asynchronous code has returned. So, you need to invoke it from the callback.

```
function buildDropdowns(data, userObject) {
  // probably you should indicate in data which field these data is for, or use
  // the userObject parameter in the google.script.run API
  autocomplete(document.getElementById("myInput"), data); 
}
```

Alternately (I haven't and won't look at the w3schools code), declare your `PMOSupport` as a const array initially, and then add the entries from your callback into it (instead of reassigning it). This way, the variable is not undefined, it is just empty at the start. Depending on the implementation of the autocomplete code, this may or may not work for you.

```
const PMOSupport = [];
....
function buildDropdowns(data) {
  PMOSupport.push(...data);
  // or
  // Array.prototype.push.apply(PMOSupport, data);
}
```

Comment: I used the second of these two suggestions; declaring PMOSupport as a const, and also iterating through my returned data to push it into that const.  Once I mage those changes, it started to give the autocomplete options.  Thank you very much!

Comment: @Andrew the spread operator should mean you don't need to explicitly iterate through `data` and push each individual element - it does that for you and [is supported by all reasonable browsers at this point](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_syntax)

Comment: I had never seen that spread operator before (I cobble things together, as opposed to being an actual developer), so I didn't understand that in your original answer.  Now that I'm looking through the link you provided, that make much more sense to me.  Thank you for helping to add something new to my toolbox.